# Central Fragment of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I currently doing research and I define a central fragment stated as follows.

A **central fragment** of a graph $G$ denoted as $\mathcal{C}(G)$,  where $\mathcal{C}(G)$ is a subgraph of  $G$ , satisfying the following condition;

1. $\mathcal{C}(G)$ is connected,
2. $\mathcal{C}(G)$ is a bridge graph,
3. $\mathcal{C}(G)$ is non-traceable,
4. $\mathcal{C}(G)$ must contain vertices of degree  1 and  of degree 3 only.

I have 2 classifications for this definition. First is central fragment are trees and the other one is graphs derived from a trees that satisfies the condition. See this for reference http://graphonline.ru/en/?graph=xrBRXlczAkGzxToh . Actually this graph can be extended by adding vertices and edge which preserves the condition. I found one classes of graph satisfying my definition see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268160754_Graceful_graphs_from_hairy_cycles. It is a hairy cycle in the form of $C\odot1K1$.

Are there any known classes of graphs satisfying the above condition?